# Cannot read connection string defined in local.settings.json

Tags: c#, azure-functions, azure-functions-core-tools

Basically, I can get my code to load connection string from local.settings.json.

I use Visual Studio 2019 to develop HTTP triggered Azure Functions (v3) locally.
I defined a `Startup` class that initializes and injects a CosmosDB client so that all functions can reference it (as shown below).
Before instantiating CosmosDB client, `ConfigurationManager` is used to get a connection string for CosmosDB.

```cs
using System.Configuration;
using AttendanceTaking.Infra.CosmosDB;
using Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Fluent;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

[assembly: FunctionsStartup(typeof(Hello.Startup))]
namespace Hello
{
    class Startup : FunctionsStartup
    {
        public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.Services.AddSingleton((service) =>
           {
               var connectionString = getConnectionString("CosmosDB");
               var cosmosClientBuilder = new CosmosClientBuilder(connectionString);
               return cosmosClientBuilder.Build();
           });
        }

        private string getConnectionString(string configName)
        {
            return ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[configName].ConnectionString;
        }
    }
}
```

The connection string itself is defined in `local.settings.json` as show below.

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet"
  },
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "CosmosDB": "AccountEndpoint=account-endpoint-secret;"
  }
}
```

Then I run my function and whenever I send a request to the HTTP endpoint, an exception is thrown at `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[configName].ConnectionString;`, saying,

> System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'
> System.Configuration.ConnectionStringSettingsCollection.this[string].get returned null.

What am I doing wrongly here?

Comment: `ConfigurationManager` isn't supported anymore. Use asp.net core config. https://blog.jongallant.com/2018/01/azure-function-config/

Comment: Omg... thank you so much...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use two methods here.

1. Environment variables

I think you can get the connection string with the `Environment variables`, because you can call `System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable` to get the connection string both when developing locally and when running in Azure.

The method of obtaining environment variables is as follows:

```
    public static string GetEnvironmentVariable(string name)
    {
        return name + ": " +
            System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable(name, EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);
    }
```

Then you can use this format to get the value of the environment variable:

```
GetEnvironmentVariable("ConnectionStrings:CosmosDB");
```

For more details, you can refer to the official [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-class-library#environment-variables).

2. ASP.NET Core Configuration

As Chris mentioned in the comments, you can use `ASP.NET Core Configuration`. For more information, you can refer to this official [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-3.1)